# Count the characters in tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there any way by which I can count the characters entered in tinymce editor. I just want to set minimum character requirement. Or how to use `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()` properly for this purpose.

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the better way to do this is using the [getContent](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent) api:

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent().length

// Get the raw text of the currently active editor
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'text'}).length;

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinymce.get('content id').getContent().length
```

Please note the usage of the `format` parameter in the second example in order to get the raw text instead of the parsed text with HTML tags.

Comment: A perfect solution for those on version 4 where the wordcount plugin it's still limited to only words (and you don't have the option to upgrade of course).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ->

```
 var body = tinymce.get("txtTinyMCE").getBody();
 var content = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);
 return content.length;
```

See -> http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Character-Count-and-Character-Limit-validation-for-TinyMCE-editor-using-JavaScript.aspx